# Who has access to the html that makes up a Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

Someone on Stack Overflow hardcoded text in the *About Me* section of my profile.

Do moderators have access to this?

Below is the text area tag..

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input processed" name="AboutMe" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="4" placeholder="BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.org, an awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. My kids are cuter than yours.
FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
&quot;If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see people helping.&quot;-Fred Rogers" data-default="" data-site=""></textarea>
```

Plain Text:

```
BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.org, an awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. 
My kids are cuter than yours.
FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see people helping.
```

Comment: It's placeholder text. Start typing in there and you'll see it disappear. Also: You might want to make your question clearer that you're talking specifically about the "Edit" section of your profile, not the display.

Comment: Though someone did manage to end up with this on their visible profile. Perhaps intentionally. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3452657/raccoon

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/123230/stella-biderman

Answer (score 29):

You are looking at the *sample placeholder text*. It is there to give you an idea about what kind of text to put in the *About me* field.

Your actual profile does not contain that text, no-one hacked your profile.

Moderators can edit the section, but only do so if there is, say, highly offensive (racist) content there needs to be removed. We won't ever *add* text there.

Note that the text is entered in the [*`placeholder` attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-placeholder) of the `<textarea>` tag. Actual contents of the field would be placed between the tags instead; browsers show the placeholder text only when there is no actual content for the field:

```html
<textarea placeholder="This is sample text">This is actual text</textarea>
```

would display a text area with the text *This is actual text* until you were to clear that text from the box.

Comment: Sometimes when Firefox crash, it uses the placeholder as text. which is why you see questions with "What's your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific." titles.