# Has my account been hacked?

Tags: support

Resently I viewed my profile on stackoverflow and discovered this kinda strange thing in the "About me" field:
[image]

It's definitely not written by me, so is it some default thing that gets written in that field, or my account has been hacked?

P.S. sorry if this is somewhat stupid question.

Comment: Was this on a shared machine?

Comment: Ah, no, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292287/who-has-access-to-the-html-that-makes-up-a-stack-overflow-profile

Comment: Marked as duplicate of When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”? Somebody hasn't had their coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a place holder - just to give you an idea of what you can put there.

You will note that the moment you type *anything* in there, that text is gone.

Comment: Ok then, thank you for pointing out. I'll accept the answer after timeout of 15 min.

Comment: BTW - what brower/OS do you use? That placeholder doesn't look as it does on my machine. Is it FireFox on Linux?

Comment: This *is* admittedly somewhat confusing - as a placeholder you'd usually expect something like http://www.kameramuseum.de/fotogalerie/vita/kt-passfoto.jpg and what you get here is https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/39/aa/4f/39aa4f3a60211aeb7ee59bd3e74ff10e.jpg definitely more fun to read though.

Comment: Yep, It's Firefox on Ubuntu Linux
(version is a bit old by the way - it's firefox 31.0 :)

Comment: Honestly, I'd've probably done a double-take on that, too. It reads like a fourth grade yearbook bio. Any reason for that?

Comment: @MikeM. - Just a bit of fun. And to get people to notice it is there ;)

Comment: The fact that the text that is currently in the box goes away the moment you start to write something is not a guarantee that it is not used. Some fields behave like this even though the current text is in use (but what often happens then is that the text is selected when you click in the field to write in it).