# I did not save this to my profile

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

In the same way as: [Who has access to the html that makes up a Stack Overflow profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292287/6220751)

Somehow my profile has the default text saved.

I do not remember ever saving that.

Is there any history to know when that happened?

[image]

Comment: Did you change your profile on any other network site?

Comment: Not that I know of @Makoto

Comment: Do you use Firefox? Apparently that can cause some issues, according to Braiam's comment on the answer there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292287/who-has-access-to-the-html-that-makes-up-a-stack-overflow-profile#comment284578_292291

Comment: Nope. I do not have that extension.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using (names and versions please)?

Comment: I am on Chrome currently. But I do not know when it happened. I just noticed it @Oded

Comment: Looks like it happened some time in June.

Comment: I really do not use Firefox @Oded Chrome is my main browser